# Choose academic or non-academic affiliation in cover letter?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, affiliation

I am preparing to submit my first research paper to a peer-reviewed journal and am at the stage of writing a cover letter to support my submission. I am technically affiliated with 2 different organisations: the non-academic research organisation where I am physically based and employed by, and the university with whom I am doing my PhD (this paper will be a chapter in my thesis).

I have both as affiliations against my name on the paper's title page, but **which should I choose to have as my affiliation when writing my contact details?** From an editor's point of view, does an academic institute appear more 'impressive' or doesn't it matter (i.e. is this simply a formality of needing some form of current contact details)?

Comment: Confirm the research organization does not own all of your intellectual property. They may own your paper or have policies related to employee publications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor won't be impressed by such things, only by the paper and the comments of reviewers. Use the affiliation by which it will be easiest to contact you. (see caveat below)

But, your advisor may have a suggestion here, possibly preferring the university since this is part of a thesis.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the address at which you would prefer to receive your correspondence.